# Scala: Converting Iterator to RDD

Tags: scala, rdd

Input : `MyRDD.collect()`

```
Array[(String, List[Int])] = Array((4,List(97, 99, 101, 102, 103)), (8,List(97, 98, 99, 102, 103, 104)), (19,List(97, 98, 102)), (15,List(97, 99, 101))
```

Output:

```
Array[(String, List[Int])] = Array((4,List(97, 99, 101, 102, 103)), (8,List(97, 98, 99, 102, 103, 104)), (19,List(97, 98, 102)), (15,List(97, 99, 101))
```

Function Call: `MyRDD.mapPartitions(myfunc).collect()`

I'm trying to convert the Iterator to RDD inside myfunc() to perform few other transformations on it.

```
def myfunc(chunk : Iterator[(String, List[Int])] ): Iterator[Int] =
{

  var k = 1
  var a=chunk.toMap
  val trainRdd: RDD[(String, List[Int])]  =   sc.parallelize(a.toSeq).map{case (k,v) => (k,v)}

//Will perform few operations on RDD in next few steps

 return Iterator(k)
}
```

while the conversion code works fine in scala shell when executed without the function, the same line of code doesn't seem to be working inside the function. Assume the RDD has atleast 2 partitions. It throws Null pointer exception which is shown below.

```
ERROR Executor: Exception in task 1.0 in stage 7.0 (TID 10)
java.lang.NullPointerException
at      $line46.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.somefuncpartition(<console>:37)
at $line47.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$anonfun$1.apply(<console>:44)
at $line47.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$anonfun$1.apply(<console>:44)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitions$1$$anonfun$apply$23.apply(RDD.scala:797)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitions$1$$anonfun$apply$23.apply(RDD.scala:797)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:108)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:338)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
18/03/01 00:09:44 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 7.0 (TID 9)
java.lang.NullPointerException
at $line46.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.somefuncpartition(<console>:37)
at $line47.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$anonfun$1.apply(<console>:44)
at $line47.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$anonfun$1.apply(<console>:44)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitions$1$$anonfun$apply$23.apply(RDD.scala:797)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitions$1$$anonfun$apply$23.apply(RDD.scala:797)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:108)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:338)
at   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
18/03/01 00:09:45 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 1.0 in stage 7.0 (TID 10,  localhost, executor driver): java.lang.NullPointerException
at $line46.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.somefuncpartition(<console>:37)
at $line47.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$anonfun$1.apply(<console>:44)
at $line47.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$anonfun$1.apply(<console>:44)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitions$1$$anonfun$apply$23.apply(RDD.scala:797)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitions$1$$anonfun$apply$23.apply(RDD.scala:797)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:108)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:338)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

18/03/01 00:09:45 ERROR TaskSetManager: Task 1 in stage 7.0 failed 1 times; aborting job
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 1  in stage 7.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 1.0 in stage 7.0   (TID 10, localhost, executor driver): java.lang.NullPointerException
at somefuncpartition(<console>:37)
at $anonfun$1.apply(<console>:44)
at $anonfun$1.apply(<console>:44)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitions$1$$anonfun$apply$23.apply(RDD.scala:797)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitions$1$$anonfun$apply$23.apply(RDD.scala:797)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:108)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:338)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Driver stacktrace:
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGSchedule r$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1517)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1505)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1504)
at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1504)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:814)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:814)
at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:814)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1732)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1687)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1676)
at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:630)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2029)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2050)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2069)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2094)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$collect$1.apply(RDD.scala:936)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:362)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.collect(RDD.scala:935) ... 48 elided
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at somefuncpartition(<console>:37)
at $anonfun$1.apply(<console>:44)
at $anonfun$1.apply(<console>:44)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitions$1$$anonfun$apply$23.apply(RDD.scala:797)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitions$1$$anonfun$apply$23.apply(RDD.scala:797)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:108)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:338)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: you had to pass the sparkContext instace object as well

Comment: @RameshMaharjan Could you please explain me bit more. I'm a newbie to scala

Comment: You have to update the question with how you are calling myfunc function

Comment: @RameshMaharjan: Function Call: MyRDD.mapPartitions(somefuncpartition).collect() . I have mentioned it at the top of the question

Comment: @RameshMaharjan I'm sorry, it is MyRDD.mapPartitions(myfunc).collect()

Comment: why would you want to create rdd inside mapPartition function call inside another function? Thats the point where you are getting nullpointer as sc cannot be identified

Comment: @RameshMaharjan I would like to perform few transformations on the data that comes inside myfunc() to achieve my program output. Is there a way to create or pass SC object to myfunc()

Comment: @RameshMaharjanThe whole idea is to take each partition of data and perform some transformations on it, to achieve the desired program result.

Comment: What kind of transformation ? Can you update the question with an explanation?

Comment: @RameshMaharjan I had to perform transformations like flatMapValues, filter etc. From the documentation I could see that iterators only map and reduce functions.

Comment: @RameshMaharjan But your clue that "sc is not identified" helped me figure out a workaround. I really appreciate your help

Comment: So it means  you figured it out right?

Comment: @RameshMaharjan yes, I figured out a work around

Comment: You can answer it below then :) or you can delete this post then. whatever you choose